# the area of the region that is outside the curve $r=1 - \cos\theta$ but inside the curve $r=1$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Find the area of the region that is outside the curve $r=1 - \cos\theta$ but inside the curve $r=1$.

Drawing the graphs, one way to get the desired area is to first obtain the area of the semicircle ($\pi/2$) and subtract from it $2\times$ the integral from $0$ to $\pi/4$ for the curve $r=1-\cos\theta$. Therefore, I set up the equation to be $\frac{\pi}{2} - 2\cdot0.5\cdot \int_{0}^{\pi/4} (1-\cos(\theta))^2 \,d\theta = \frac{\pi}{8} + \sqrt{2} - \frac{1}{4}$. However, this is not the right answer. Where might I have gone wrong?

Comment: Why $\pi/4$, not $\pi/2$, for as much as i see $(1-\cos(\pi/2)) = 1$ ?

Answer (score 2):

The area that you are interested in is the area of the region outside the blue cardioid and inside the red circle in the picture below:

[image]

The area of the part of the cardioid located in the first and fourth quadrants is$$\int_{-\frac\pi2}^\frac\pi2(1-\cos\theta)^2\,\mathrm d\theta=\frac{3\pi}2-4.$$So, the area that your after is equal to$$\frac\pi2-\left(\frac{3\pi}2-4\right)=4-\pi.$$

Comment: Interesting: that's the same as the area between the circle and its circumscribed square.

Comment: That's a nice remark.